# Como Mostrar Las Aplicaciones Del Usuario Desde La Mía

Tags: android

Estoy intentando mostrar las aplicaciones del usuario desde la mía.

He intentado mostrarlas en un `listView` tratando de mostrar los datos del usuario en la ruta `data/app`, pero cuando iniciaba se cerraba y decía error por la razón de que esa ruta se prohíbe el acceso, a menos de que se sea usuario *root*.

Quiero hacer un app que permita hacer backup a las aplicaciones, activar, desactivar y desinstalar, o también programar cuando se activen.

Comment: Te refieres a listar las aplicaciones que se encuentran en el dispositivo en un listado. Esto desde una aplicación tuya?

Comment: Si eso mismo. Si me puedes ayudar de lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno para mostrar las aplicaciones instaladas en un dispositivo puedes utilizar este código:

```
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> AppsList =   getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo appInfo : AppsList){
        String name = appInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    }
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por el aporte que me acabas de dar lo voy a probar te mantendré informado si me funciono, muchas gracias es enserio

Comment: Una perguntica o mas bien un favorcito. Si es que me puedes explicar ese código mostrado y si puedes también darme un consejo de como aprovecharlo mejor porque soy novato en esto. Si por favor.

Comment: @AJoseAbrahanP.Castañeda no hay complicación alguna, recomiendo que aprendas primero un poco de programación en Java/android, con cosas faciles, el código recorre una lista appslist y cada elemento "app instalada" esta dentro de appInfo

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: @AJoseAbrahanP.Castañeda como complemento te dejo la referencia de la clase ResolveInfo https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html , también si tu duda fue resuelta puedes marcarla como resuelta. Saludos.

Comment: No soy muy experto manejando las características de esta pagina me dices como marcar como resulta.